# AuthenticationProvider authenticate called twice in IE and fails to login

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security

I have a custom `AuthenticationProvider` with the `authenticate` method.

```
    @Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        > Check username, password, throw exceptions where needed

        return new CustomAuthenticationToken(username, grantedAuthorities);
    }
```

And the token:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
{
     public CustomAuthenticationToken(ICurrentUserContext currentUser, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
         super(currentUser.getUsername(), currentUser.getPassword(), authorities);
     }
}
```

When I login with Chrome, Firefox, there is no problem whatsoever.

In IE 8/9 I have a very weird problem. Sometimes it will only call the method `authenticate` one time, it will login and everything works as expected. But from time to time, it will call `authenticate` twice, and fails to log in.

Does anybody have any clue?

I've tested it on Tomcat btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem, with careful tracing the debug log of the Spring Security.. Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

Apparantly, spring security default migrates sessions after login. But in IE it does not migrate the authentication cookie to the new session, resulting in presenting of the login page.

The fix is easy, and can be done in the Spring Security xml:

```xml
<http use-expressions="true">

    <!-- 
        This settings is for IE. Default this setting is on migrateSession.
        When IE tries to migrate the session, the auth cookie does not migrate,
        resulting in a nice login screen again, after you've logged in.

        This setting ensures that the session will not be invalidated, and thus IE will still work as expected.
     -->
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />
</http>
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. The browser shouldn't know anything about session-migration, other than seeing a new `JSESSIONID` cookie being set on the response. Please take a look at my separate answer and see if that applies. Since this serves a specific purpose, it's better if you can avoid disabling it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this please [Internet Explorer buggy when accessing a custom weblogic provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3047302/502950).

Maybe you habe to disable cookies no your Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Migrating the session is entirely a server-side process and should be invisible to the browser. All it should see is a new `Set-Cookie` header for the JSESSIONID, which it should respect.

My best guess is that you are seeing [this tomcat bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49158), which will cause different effects depending on how a browser interprets the duplicate headers. It was originally reported because of [this issue with a Blackberry browser](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1462) which is closely related to what you're seeing here.

But you don't say which versions of either Spring Security or Tomcat you are using (always a good idea :-)), so it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Yes, but how to go from here.. I am using the vFabric tc Server v2.7, with Spring 3.0

Comment: Apparantly, IE does not respect the Set-Cookie header?

Comment: All browsers should respect that header (they wouldn't work with cookies at all otherwise). What version of Spring Security are you using? 3.0 isn't a specific version number. You best option is to debug the actual responses in a browser plugin and see whether this even applies (i.e. do you see the cookie being set, and are there multiple headers setting the same cookie). Then try it on a current tomcat version and see if it works.

Comment: Spring Security: 3.1.0.RELEASE, Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.. The thing is.. that I do not have a choice if this gets installed at the customers Tomcat. He/she just wants it to work, even on older Tomcat installations. So instead of me discarding it as a Tomcat issue, I'd rather see it work! ;)

Comment: If the customer is using a buggy tomcat, then they should upgrade. There isn't really another solution. But first you should check whether it actually happens.

Comment: I see a Set-Cookie header for the post on the redirect page in IE developer tools. 
`Set-Cookie JSESSIONID=BB6C764FB423BD31DF28994D480588F1; Path=/myApplication/; HttpOnly`. I also see another JSESSIONID guid being sent than the one I received.. I think that is because it migrates the session, right? Any clues? :)

Comment: I know customers should upgrade buggy application servers, but in larger co-operations this is not something that can be done instantly.. Sometimes it can take months due to policies and what not.., and the business wants to see it work yesterday, rather than today.. ;)

Comment: Also, awesome that a developer of SpringSource is looking at my problem! It is much appreciated! :)

Comment: If you see two `Set-Cookie` headers for `JSESSIONID` in the same response, then it is an application server bug (most likely the one I referred you to). A cookie can only have one value in the browser.

Comment: I see only one header.. I do have to add that this problem occurs the most directly after logging out, and logging back in again..

Answer (score 0):

Table of contents
Quick Reference
Spring Security Core plugin
<< 17IP Address Restrictions19Logout Handlers >>
18 Session Fixation Prevention - Reference Documentation
Authors: Burt Beckwith, Beverley Talbott
Version: 2.0-RC3
18 Session Fixation Prevention
To guard against session-fixation attacks set the useSessionFixationPrevention attribute to true:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSessionFixationPrevention = true
Upon successful authentication a new HTTP session is created and the previous session's attributes are copied into it. If you start your session by clicking a link that was generated by someone trying to hack your account, which contained an active session id, you are no longer sharing the previous session after login. You have your own session.

Session fixation is less of a problem now that Grails by default does not include jsessionid in URLs (see this JIRA issue), but it's still a good idea to use this feature.

Note that there is an issue when using the cookie-session plugin; see this issue for more details.

The table shows configuration options for session fixation.

Property    Default Value   Meaning
useSessionFixationPrevention    true    Whether to use session fixation prevention.
sessionFixationPrevention.migrate   true    Whether to copy the session attributes of the existing session to the new session after login.
sessionFixationPrevention.alwaysCreateSession   false   Whether to always create a session even if one did not exist at the start of the request.

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/sessionFixation.html

Comment: No Grails my friend :)